# Ubuntu persistent usb drive partitions

Tags: partitioning, usb

So I recently made half of my 256gb usb drive a persistent, portable ubuntu os. The other half is a regular usb drive for files and whatnot. The only issue I have is when I plug it in on windows, windows sees all the partitions for ubuntu and gives them drive letters and they show up in file manager like a usb drive, but when I try to access them windows trys to format them. I went into disk manager and the partitions show up and they don't have drive letters, but they do in file manager. Is there a way I can hide these partitions from windows? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome! This would seem a windows question, which is off-topic. Windows and ext partitions don't mix well.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu in the USB? Did you first create another Live-USB and then install from that to this USB? Or did you use a program in Windows to create this USB? Can you take a screenshot of gparted showing the partitions of the USB? Then upload the screenshot to imgur.com. Then edit your question and put a link to the uploaded file in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately Windows does not like the ext4 file system and other Linux file systems. I don't think we can stop Windows from ***suggesting to format*** partitions with such file systems, but we can ***avoid doing that*** because we know that they are valuable for Ubuntu.

Comment: My Windows 10 computer only sees Windows partitions such as FAT and NTFS, not ext3 or ext4 or ISO9660. Do you have **Ext2Fsd** or other Linux driver installed? https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/ Perhaps you may need to delete one of these drivers. I have Diskinternals installed in Windows, but I need to open it to see Linux drives.

Answer (score 0):

You can format non-system partitions as exFAT and they will be compatible with both Linux and Windows.

You can use the Disks application to do this.

Your Ubuntu installation might require `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` packages, depending on the kernel in use.